# How to extract 2D Array from C# text box with multi line strings?

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble to extract a 2D array from the text. However, I'm able to get the 2D array if I read it from text files. Here's what I got when reading txt files and extract it to 2D array:

```
var array = File.ReadLines(path)
                    .Select(line => line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    .ToArray();
```

Below are my codes when I tried to extract strings from textbox to 2d array, but I only able to get single dimension array. What is the equivalent of Select(line => line when using textbox?

```
var array = richTextBox1.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .ToArray();
```

How can I replicate the same results when extracting it from the text box?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var array = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n').Select(line => line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .ToArray();
```

Basically, you want to split by line breaks to achieve the same effect as `File.ReadLines`.

Comment: Does the RichTextBox use `\n` or rather `Environment.NewLine` as separator?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel I'm not actually sure, if anybody knows feel free to edit

Comment: @mousetail tried your method and got an error saying 'cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'. and I changed "\n" to '\n' and now it works! Thank you so much!!